# How to move file in vb.net 2022

Tags: vb.net

I'm making an app for moving an image to one folder to another. but when i use this code below

```
'Defining the source path
        Dim sourcepath As String
        sourcepath = SourceFolderPath.Text + "\" + ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString

        'Defining the destination path
        Dim targetpath As String
        targetpath = Folder1Path.Text + "\" + ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString


        'Move file
        ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
        PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
        My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile(sourcepath, targetpath)
```

it always throw error "the file is in use by another process" which when i checked it, it was only used by my app only.

is there any idea how to move files from sourcepath to destinationpath, thanks in advance

Comment: Firstly, use the `System.IO.Path` class to manipulate file and folder paths. Secondly, if you want the text displayed in a `ListBox` for the `SelectedItem` then use the `Text` property. `Dim sourcePath = Path.Combine(SourceFolderPath.Text, ListBox1.Text)`.

Comment: Setting the Image property to nothing doesn't free the lock on the file (at least not immediately). Try to use _PictureBox1.Image.Dispose()_

Comment: As for the issue, there's nothing in the code you posted that explains the issue. Either you have opened the source or target file somewhere else in your code that you haven't shown us or you have one open in another application.

Comment: If you have loaded an image into a `PictureBox` by calling `Image.FromFile` to create the `Image` object, that will be the issue. Instead, set the `ImageLocation` property of the control. That will load the image without locking the file. Then you don't even have to clear the control, never mind dispose anything.

Comment: i've changed all Image.FromFile to ImageLocation and it work like a charm, now i can move the file without an issues, thanks guys for helping me :)